# Create a column by groupby Pandas DataFrame based on tail(1).index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I want create a boolean column that said if a match on first or second half for each match in the dataframe.
Code

```
#First Half
firsthalf_index = df.groupby(['Date','Match']).apply(lambda x: x[(x.M >= 1) & (x.M <= 45)].tail(1).index)

#Second Half
secondhalf_index = df.groupby(['Date','Match']).apply(lambda x: x[(x.M >= 46) & (x.M <= 90)].tail(1).index)
```

This code return only the referred.index for each game

Output
[image]

What I want to add in this code is `df[df.index < firsthalfindex_index]` and `df[(df.index > firsthalfindex.index) & (df.index < secondhalf_index)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
firsthalf_index = ((df.M >= 1) & (df.M <= 45)).iloc[::-1].groupby([df['Date'],df['Match']]).transform('idxmax')
secondhalf_index =((df.M >= 46) & (df.M <= 90)).iloc[::-1].groupby([df['Date'],df['Match']]).transform('idxmax')
```

Then

```
s = df.index.to_series()
df[(s > firsthalf_index) & (s < secondhalf_index)]
```

Comment: It works, I had sort index like this `df1 = df[(s < firsthalf_index.sort_index())]` and `df2 = df[(s > firsthalf_index.sort_index()) & (s < secondhalf_index.sort_index())]` then I set the column and concat the dfs `df1['HalfTime'] = 'ht1'
df2['HalfTime'] = 'ht2'
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])`.
Thanks!